# XSLT to rename link targets in result-document()

Tags: xslt

When splitting a deeply nested XML document into multiple output files using result-document(), is there a method to rewrite the @href values to point to ids inside the new documents? For example, splitting a book into multiple documents based on each  becoming a new file, named with book-part/@id. In output file for chapter 1 there may be a link to a target in output file for chapter 2, which link value used to be relative within the single file. Now this link pointing to a different file should have the file name of chapter 2 followed by # and the original target value. There are changes to make the proper linking element (related-object), too, but it is the target value that I'm trying to generate specifically.
i.e link target pattern: [outputfilename.xml]#[original-filetarget-id]

It seems that I need to gather the values of each @rid in the original file and check before I insert the filename if the target will be in a different file and write the output @document-id according to the file in which it will be output. But I'm having trouble understanding how I would know the output file name and where in the XSLT to rewrite the target.

source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD Book DTD v2.1 20050630//EN" "book.dtd">
<book dtd-version="3.0">
    <book-meta>
        <book-id>123.4567890</book-id>
    </book-meta>
    <body>
        <book-part book-part-type="chapter" id="book.123.4567890.ch01">
            <book-part-meta>
                <title-group>
                    <title>Chapter 1</title>
                </title-group>
            </book-part-meta>
            <body>
                <p> some text with a <xref rid="a">link to chapter 1</xref></p>
                <p> some text with a <xref rid="b">link to chapter 2</xref></p>
                <p id="a">a target id in chapter 1</p>
            </body>
        </book-part>
        <book-part book-part-type="chapter" id="book.123.4567890.ch02">
            <book-part-meta>
                <title-group>
                    <title>Chapter 2</title>
                </title-group>
            </book-part-meta>
            <body>
                <p> some text with a <xref rid="a">link to chapter 1</xref></p>
                <p> some text with a <xref rid="b">link to chapter 2</xref></p>
                <p id="b">a target id in chapter 1</p>
            </body>
        </book-part>
    </body>
</book>
```

output book.123.4567890.ch01.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD Book DTD v2.1 20050630//EN" "book.dtd">
<book dtd-version="3.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oasis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/oasis-exchange/table">
    <book-meta>
        <book-id>123.4567890</book-id>
    </book-meta>
    <body>
        <book-part book-part-type="chapter" id="book.123.4567890.ch01">
            <book-part-meta>
                <title-group>
                        <title>Chapter 1</title>
                </title-group>
            </book-part-meta>
            <body>
                <p> some text with a <xref rid="a">link to chapter 1</xref></p>
                <p> some text with a <related-object document-type="chapter" object-id="book.123.4567890.ch02.xml#b">link to chapter 2</related-object></p>
                <p id="a">a target id in chapter 1</p>
            </body>
            </book-part>
    </body>
</book>
```

output book.123.4567890.ch02.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD Book DTD v2.1 20050630//EN" "book.dtd">
<book dtd-version="3.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oasis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/oasis-exchange/table">
    <book-meta>
        <book-id>123.4567890</book-id>
    </book-meta>
    <body>
        <book-part book-part-type="chapter" id="book.123.4567890.ch02">
            <book-part-meta>
                <title-group>
                <title>Chapter 2</title>
                </title-group>
            </book-part-meta>
            <body>
                <p> some text with a <related-object document-type="chapter" object-id="book.123.4567890.ch01.xml#a">link to chapter 1</related-object></p>
                <p> some text with a <xref rid="b" >link to chapter 2</xref></p>
                <p id="b">a target id in chapter 1</p>
            </body>
        </book-part>
    </body>
</book>
```

Comment: Try to make your question a bit shorter and clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is:  yes, you have understood correctly what you need to do.

You need to figure out, for each hyperlink, whether its target will be in the same output file as the source of the link, or a different one.  And you have correctly identified the challenge here:  knowing what the new file name will be.  It's not really as difficult as it may look at first; just take a deep breath and work it out.

You are at an xref element; it has an rid attribute. You want to know:  will the xref and the target be in the same output file or different ones?  To decide this, you must

- Ascend from the xref element to the containing book-part, and figure out what its filename will be.  Put this value in a variable (fn-xref).
- Go to the target element (`id(@rid)`) and then ascend from that element to the containing book-part, and figure out what its filename will be.  Put this value in a variable (fn-rid).
- Compare the values of $fn-xref and $fn-rid.  If they are equal, do the right thing.  If they differ, do the other right thing.

I'm guessing you don't need help turning this prose description into XSLT, but speak up if you do.

Comment: @user3396874 - if you do need help with the xslt, be sure to specify the version.